# Connectedness of A Set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Munkres asserts that the following:

$$X = \{x \times y | y = 0\}\cup\{x \times y | x>0 \text{ and }y = 1/x\}$$

is not connected. (Basically to two pieces are the graph $1/x$ and its asymptote at $0$). I'm not seeing this though:

1. If I try to find an open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ containing $\{x \times y | y = 0\}$ it will also contain the tail of $\{x \times y | x>0 \text{ and }y = 1/x\}$
2. Isn't the limit of each contained in the other? (Munkres claims its not, then stops explaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : A non-connected set is the union of two disjoints closed subsets. Try to prove that your two natural subsets are closed.

Comment: okay I see that both are continuous graphs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - so the sets contain their limits by sequential defn of limits. But now I'm really confused, because this contradicts 1 and 2 in my original question

Comment: Well, your statement $1)$ is not true : for instance, the set $O = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x \leq 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x > 0 \text{ and } |y| < 1/2x \rbrace$ is an open set containing $\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y=0 \rbrace$, but not containing the "tail" as you says. For your second statement, what do you call the "limit" of a set ?

Comment: well whatever it is, $y=0$ will be the $y$ coordinate (project $(x,y)$ coordinates to $y$ axis and see that set $\{x > 0, y = 1/x\}$ is $(0,\infty)$). isn't that enough?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The point is that you cannot have any convergent sequence of $\lbrace x > 0, y =1/x \rbrace$ whose limit $(a,b)$ has the second coordinate $b=0$. Indeed the set $\lbrace x > 0, y =1/x \rbrace$ is closed, so the limit $(a,b)$ satisfy $b=1/a$, and therefore, $b=0$ is impossible.